# When using the WebImage helper the HTTP response looks like image data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a method I am calling via AJAX form my MVC3 application. The method creates an image using the WebImage helper. After the image is created, I then return a Json result from the controller. What is actually returned looks like image data. The content type I am sendingin the headers for the request is json, so I am not sure why the server is return the image data rather than my actual json result. If I remove the WebImage code, I get the actual json result I am looking for.

Method example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTempImage(AvatarUploadModel avatar){

try{

var imageId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var newFileName = imageId + "_" + Path.GetFileName(avatar.FileName);
            var imageTempPath = Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Admin/TemporaryUploads/" + newFileName);
            var image = new WebImage(avatar.FileName).Resize(400, 400, true).Write();
            image.Save(imageTempPath);
return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
catch(Exception ex){
              return Json(new { success = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is your problem

```
var image = new WebImage(avatar.FileName).Resize(400, 400, true).Write();
```

It's documented as...

```
/// <summary>
/// Renders an image to the browser.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// The image.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="requestedFormat">(Optional) The file format to use when the image is written.    </param>
```

Decompiling it gives the following code:

```
  requestedFormat = requestedFormat ?? this._initialFormat.ToString();
  byte[] bytes = this.GetBytes(requestedFormat);
  string str = !requestedFormat.StartsWith("image/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "image/" + requestedFormat : requestedFormat;
  HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
  response.ContentType = str;
  response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
  return this;
```

i.e. it's writing the image directly to `HttpContext.Current.Response` and setting the `ContentType` to the image's format.

If you just want to save the image to the file system on the server then you can remove the call to `Write` and replace it with the call to `Save`:

```
var image = new WebImage(avatar.FileName).Resize(400, 400, true).Save(imageTempPath);
```

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: Oh man!! I didn't even notice I was adding the Write method to my code. Perfect!